# Spherical interpolation : how to rotate an object backwards?

Tags: math, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am rotating a transform with the following line:

```
Quaternion.Slerp(Quaternion qBegin, Quaternion qEnd, float deltaTime);
```

The spherical interpolation uses the shortest rotation between **qBegin** and **qEnd**.

Sometimes, I need to make this interpolation "backwards", with the longest rotation between **qBegin** and **qEnd**.

I currently achieve this by cutting my big rotation into consecutive smaller ones, but I prefer to have a proper mathematical answer rather than a "fix" approach.

My question is : *how to rotate this object backwards with elegance ?*

Comment: I don't know how many "consecutive smaller ones" you have, but you only need 2 half-rotations

Comment: yup currently using 2 half rotations

Comment: The first answer here might be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886606/flipping-issue-when-interpolating-rotations-using-quaternions

Comment: perfect, i missed this topic ! Thanks.